# Blood-compatible liquid for cooling body

Tags: blood-flow

I'm not sure if this is a good post, it might indeed be a very bad one.

I wanted to know whether it is possible to inject the body with a substance that will temporarily, say for half and l an hour out for hours, cool the interior parts off the body via the blood system.

Thanks.

Comment: What's "the interior party"?

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: I'm afraid it still has very little to do with fitness.

Comment: here you go http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12505732

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty drastic.  Maybe ingesting something like a fruit slushy, a Slurpee/Icee, or even just blended ice and some water would do the trick, as normal blood flow in and around the stomach-full of slushy ice-liquid would even out that temperature differential and cool down the body.  Beware of brain, neck and back freeze, though.

That's what I do, because I otherwise keep sweating and feel hot for one to two hours after a decent workout.